# Jaccard similarity over an adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r

I have an adjacency matrix with rows as gene names and columns as pathways.

I want to find the similarity between the rows(genes). I have to use jaccard similarity but unfortunately with dist or proxy:dist, or proxy:simil I get a value of only 0 and 1, no other values.

Please let me know if you have an idea regarding it.

Comment: Are all of the entries in the matrix either zero or one?

Comment: yes my input matrix is adjacency but I wasn't expecting my output matrix to have only 0 and 1s